# Xalan Transformer features

Tags: java, xml, xalan

I ran a Fortify scan to line security vulnerabilities.  It recommended that I set the following features to my XML Document to XML String transformer.

```
        final TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        tf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
        tf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
```

This results in an exception because those strings don't exist.  There is an option for XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, but it's not clear to me if external entities are prevented from being used.  The JavaDoc states: "true instructs the implementation to process XML securely. This may set limits on XML constructs to avoid conditions such as denial of service attacks."

```
tf.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
```

Comment: and the question is ...? :)

Comment: What does "those strings don't exist" mean?

Comment: Those are XML parser features, not XSLT transformer features. Whatever Fortify is, it's either giving you bad advice, or you have misunderstood it.

Comment: @IzCe, the question is does setting this option really prevent external entities from being processed?

Comment: @keshlam, XMLConstants does not have a constant that matches "http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities" .  The only one I found that I could use is "FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING"

Comment: @Michael Kay, what would be the equivalent way to exclude external entities in XSLT, or do I need do it as part of XML parsing?

Comment: How you do it in the XSLT processor will depend on which XSLT processor you're using and how you're invoking it.

Comment: @user994165 the XSLT processor doesn't read external entities, that's done by the XML parser. But XSLT requires external entities to be expanded if they are present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the comments above, these features need to be set in the XML parser, not the XSLT Transformer.